# Appropriate terms for activities like camping, hiking, trekking, mountaineering, wilderness survival?

Tags: hiking, survival, mountaineering, wild-camping, trekking

Outdoor adventure activities seems like a mouthful, so I was wondering if there was a more appropriate term for such activities?

Wikipedia suggests 'Outdoor Recreation' but that implies these to be leisure based activities and doesn't account for people like a lot of us here for whom it is a serious passion or pursuit.

'Outdoor sports' could be an option but it seems too broad and sports has a connotation of being competitive.

'Wilderness Adventures' seems like the only other term which would be appropriate?

What would be an appropriate term that encompasses these activities?

Posting here based on suggestions on original thread: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/350853/is-there-a-term-for-outdoor-adventure-activities-like-camping-hiking-trekking

Comment: I would suggest asking on the http://english.stackexchange.com/ site.

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh- he did: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/350853/13804.  I assume geoboy is hedging his bets.

Comment: Out of curiosity only, are you trying to come up with a brand/company name?

Comment: Cross posting is discouraged http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270047/cross-posting-between-localized-stack-overflow-versions

Comment: Its funny that I was told there to ask here, and the other way round here :) Given this is relating to the subject, I imagined there might be different set of answers given the perspectives and experience here.

Comment: I've also added a disclosure as per link posted above.

Comment: I don't understand why *outdoor recreation* is in contradiction with it for some being a *serious passion or pursuit*.

Comment: @gerrit  It is a matter of opinion.  See [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/159954?rskey=YAX72m&result=1#eid) definition of recreation.  There is a "I can take it or leave it" aspect to the word, for me.

Comment: How about *Wilderness activity*?  This is then intuitively distinct from football, golfing, [parkour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkour), etc.

Comment: @wallyk That would exclude most walking in Europe.  Someone walking from Warsaw to Santiago de Compostela meets little if any wilderness, but is certainly engaging in activities such as described in the topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it is a cross-site duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I think the term you're looking for is **Outdoorsmanship**. An outdoorsman is an individual who is interested in the pursuit of many if not all outdoor sports and recreational activities. An *extreme outdoorsman* would describe someone who takes more risks in the outdoors, such as alpinists, backcountry survivalists, etc.